# Testflight iOS8 - Non Apple ID Account

Tags: ios8, testflight, apple-id

I've just installed the latest testflight app on my personal iphone 6.

We've got a company testflight user logins which are completely separate from our personal accounts.

However when I launch the testflight app it wants to use my Apple ID - which has no access to any of the apps as they're all linked to the organisation email.

Is there a way I can logout and use my organisational account for this single app?

Thanks

Comment: Nah. nothing like that.

Answer (score 16):

Go to your Settings. Then go to iTunes & App Store. Tap your email address at the top to Sign Out and sign in with a different account.

Afterwards, you can log back into your personal account.

There is no way to sign in to your company account for just the TestFlight app.

Comment: I must say - this is an absolute joke...No formal method of proper migration is terrible...gah...

Comment: You can also just use the old TestFlight system. Add the devices to your provisioning profile, invite team members through the TestFlight website, and send them builds through Mail/Safari. This might be a better solution for now until Apple responds to this issue.

Comment: @neruka, TestFlight shuts down completely in 10 days. 
But yes, the new ITC solution for internal testers is stupid. You should be able to add internal testers to multiple accounts.

Answer (score 2):

You don't need to have Test flight on same email id. You may register with any email to receive test builds. You just need to have access to that email in your device.

Make Safari your default browser for opening links. Once you receive the email. Click on "Open in TestFlight" and it will open the Test Flight app and add the build to it.

Answer (score 1):

If you open the "Open in TestFlight" link in Safari on the device you'd like to test with it will add the beta app to the TestFlight app even if the emails don't match.

Opening the link in other browsers will not work.